# Variable is said to be not defined even though I have defined it (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

why is fin variable not defined even though I have declared it just before the for loop???

```
a  = function(...args) {
    total = 0;
    for (each of args) {
        total += each;
    }
    total = total.toString();
    while (total.length != 1) {
        var fin = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < total.length; i++) {
            fin *= parseInt(total[i]);
        }
        total = fin.toString();
    }

    return parseInt(fin);
}



a(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have `int` keyword.

Comment: you have `int i ` which is not valid in javascript. use `var i` or `let i`

Comment: `total` and `each` should be defined with `let` (or `var`). So should `a` for that matter.

Comment: `fin` is defined inside while loop and not accessible in `return int.parseInt(fin);`

Comment: @fedesc it's defined with `var` so its scope is the whole function.

Comment: @Pointy Ok, thanks for clarifying

Comment: Your fin was decreared inside while loop, and is not visible to the function . Simple put fin is a local variable and can't be seen outside the scope

Comment: @Fritzdultimate that is incorrect.

Comment: `var` is function scoped, not block scoped.  That's why `let` was introducted.

Answer (score 2):

If I remove all your `int` references it runs fine

```js
a  = function(...args) {
    total = 0;
    for (each of args) {
        total += each;
    }
    total = total.toString();
    while (total.length != 1) {
        var fin = 1;
        for (i = 0; i < total.length; i++) {
            fin *= parseInt(total[i]);
        }
        total = fin.toString();
    }

    return parseInt(fin);
}



var result = a(1,2,3,4,5,6);
console.log('result', result);
```

[edit] If I wanted to fix it in more ways, I would probably write it like this:

```js
const a = function(...args) {
    let total = 0;
    for (let each of args) {
        total += each;
    }
    total = total.toString();
    let fin;
    while (total.length != 1) {
        fin = 1;
        for (let i = 0; i < total.length; i++) {
            fin *= parseInt(total[i]);
        }
        total = fin.toString();
    }

    return parseInt(fin);
}



var result = a(1,2,3,4,5,6);
console.log('result', result);
```

Comment: Be careful, `i` is polluting the global scope.

Comment: I'm just fixing the immediate error in his code. It's a mess for other reasons than that, sure, but it runs now haha

Answer (score 2):

You're using an `int` keyword that doesn't exist, as well as some undefined `int` object. What you're trying to do is this:

```js
a  = function(...args) {
    total = 0;
    for (each of args) {
        total += each;
    }
    total = total.toString();
    while (total.length != 1) {
        var fin = 1;
        for (let i = 0; i < total.length; i++) {
            fin *= parseInt(total[i]);
        }
        total = fin.toString();
    }

    return parseInt(fin);
}



console.log(a(1,2,3,4,5,6));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of changes that you need to do in order to make this code functional.

1. JavaScript will not understand anything such as **int** ( as it is not strongly typed), so in the for loop remove the int keyword and use let or var instead.

   for (**let** i = 0; i < total.length; i++)
2. Instead of **int.parseInt** you will have to use fin *= Number.parseInt(total[i]);